# Adding a C++ addon causes the packaged app to crash, but it works if I run 'yarn start'

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am using Electron-builder to package my app.

**Version**:  22.4.0

**Target**:  nsis

Adding a custom grpc client addon written in C++ is crashing the packaged app. After I run `yarn dist` and I install the app using the resultant setup exe, I try and start the app. But the screen goes white (i.e., it loads nothing) and after 5 seconds or so, the app crashes. If I start the app from node using `yarn/npm start`, it works properly, so I do not think that the problem is with the addon itself, probably my settings in `package.json`; since that's what has caused me the most pain till now.

My package json file:

```
{
  "name": "XYXYXYX",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "nodeGypRebuild":"true",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "xfilter.optima",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "runAfterFinish": false
    }
  },
  "author": "XXXX",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
    "is-unc-path": "^1.0.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.2",
    "node-addon-api": "*",
    "sharp": "^0.24.1",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.75"
  }
}
```

Also, interestingly the app doesn't seem to crash at the `require()` statement, rather when I run a function that I have exported from my C++ side.

The C++ surface (just in case) :

```
#include <napi.h>

#include <ApiWorker.h>

using namespace Napi;

void runFilter(const CallbackInfo& info)
{
    String panel_id =  info[0].As<String>();
    Function callback = info[1].As<Function>();

    ApiWorker* _apiworker = new ApiWorker(panel_id, callback);
    _apiworker->Queue();
}

Object Init(Env env, Object exports)
{
    exports.Set(String::New(env, "runFilter"),
                Function::New(env, runFilter));

    return exports;    
}

NODE_API_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
```

I am trying to call `runFilter()` like

```
const filter = require('addon.node')
filter.runFilter("foobar", () => {console.log("Done");})
```

`ApiWorker` is an `AsyncWorker` (derived from `Napi::AsyncWorker`)

PS: If I run in dev mode, then the devtools crash (see attachment)
[image: Annotation 2020-03-27 012341]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permissions issue.

See [#4818](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4818).

> Figured out what the issue was. Because of "perMachine": true and
>   "allowElevation": true, the program was getting installed into
>   C:\ProgramFiles as an elevated user. But when I run it, it runs as a
>   lower level user who doesn't have permission to write to the folder.
>
> Can be fixed by only installing for the current user (i.e.
>   "perMachine": false)